# Project Installer Not using App.config Transform from Project Output

Tags: visual-studio, app-config, setup-project

I'm using the [Visual Studio 2013 Project](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d) Installer extension.  In my installer project, I am selecting to use the Primary Output from another project, called the Program Project.  The PP is a console application that has an app.config with transform files using this [config](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859) extension. Building the PP with various configurations is correctly picking up the transform values. But my installer project, won't pick up the correct transform values even though I have selected the correct config file to use with the output from the PP. Instead, it is only grabbing whatever values are in the PP's root app.config file.
[image]
[image]

It is not get the values from app.*debug*.config. It is using the app.config file.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? Do you remember how?